# CSS Issues on Safari: Unexpected space in a div

Tags: css, safari

https://codepen.io/06444929923/pen/gOMKaJd

```
<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2 MuiGrid-direction-xs-column">
  <div class="x-a MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item">
    <div class="x-b">
      <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2">
        <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-auto">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-true">
          Lorem
        </div>
        <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-auto">
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created a codepen as above to demonstrate the issue. Classes for material UI are also included. It is all okay when viewing the page using chrome. However, unexpected spaces are inserted into the div for Safari.

The yellow div should have the same height as the blue one however it isn't in Safari. It is not margin or padding when I inspect using developer tools. What is causing the issue?